# jQuery Validate not validating on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I'm facing some problems with jQuery Validate. I've already put the rules but when i'm submitting the form, nothing happens.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

**EDIT: [Click here](http://pastebin.com/3nEz0qyi) to see my entire code. I'm trying to post it here but i'm getting the following error: 403 Forbidden: IPS signature match**. Below is part of my code with Andrei Dvoynos's suggestion. I'm getting the same error. Clicking on submit and the page being reloaded

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section Teste1{
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#moeda").maskMoney();
        $("#percent").maskMoney();
        $(":input").inputmask();
          $('#tel').focusout(function () {
            var phone, element;
            element = $(this);
            element.unmask();
            phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
            if (phone.length > 10) {
                element.inputmask({ "mask": "(99) 99999-999[9]" });
            } else {
                element.inputmask({ "mask": "(99) 9999-9999[9]" });
            }
          }).trigger('focusout');
//the code suggested by Andrei Dvoynos, i've tried but it's occurring the same.
        $("#form1").validate({
          rules: {
             cpf: { required: true, },
             cep: { required: true, },
             tel: { required: true, },
             email: { required: true, },
             cnpj: { required: true, },
          },
          highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
          },
          unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
          },
          errorElement: 'span',
          errorClass: 'help-block'
        });            
    });
</script>
}
@using (@Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post,
             new { id = "form1", name = "form1" }))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Sign In</legend>
    <div class="form-group" id="divCpf">
        <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
        <input data-inputmask="'mask': '999.999.999-99'" class="form-control" id="cpf" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="divCep">
        <label for="cep">CEP</label>
        <input data-inputmask="'mask' : '99999-999'" type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" placeholder="CEP" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="divTel">
        <label for="tel">Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="tel" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="email">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="divcnpj">
        <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
        <input data-inputmask="'mask' : '99.999.999/9999-99'" type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="moeda">Moeda</label>
        <input type="text" id="moeda" data-allow-zero="true" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Percent">Percent</label>
        <input type="text" id="percent" data-suffix="%" data-allow-zero="true" class="form-control" maxlength="7" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign In" id="sign" />
</fieldset>
}
```

My tests (all unsuccessful):

1 - put the `$("form").validate()` into `$(document).ready()`

2 - put the `required` class on the fields.

**jQuery Validate plugin version: 1.13.0**

Comment: Did you mean to paste some of your code in and forgot?

Comment: You have to put the validation inside the anonymous function passed as parameter to the ready() method.

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm trying to submit the remaining code, but i'm getting the error:

"an error ocurred when submitting the edit"

Comment: Hey @ChrisBenseler. I've tried to do it, but the same happen.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you try because you broke the plugin by neglecting to contain all of your rules inside of the `rules` option.  Then you should place your `.validate()` call within the DOM ready event handler function so that it's initialized on the form _after_ the HTML is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the fatal problem you fixed thanks to @Andrei, you also have one more fatal flaw.  The `name` attribute is missing from your inputs.

- Every element **must** contain a unique `name` attribute.  This is a requirement of the plugin because it's how it keeps track of every input.
- The `name` is the target for declaring rules inside of the `rules` option.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {    // <-  all rule declarations must be contained within 'rules' option
        cpf: {  // <-  this is the NAME attribute
            required: true,
        ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3tLzh/**

Comment: You just killed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't see how this is any different from my answer :) But glad its fixed, cheers.

Comment: Oh I see it now. His html code is also missing the name attribute! Heh, good catch

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `rules` property when calling the validate function, try something like this:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        cpf: { required: true, },
        cep: { required: true, },
        tel: { required: true, },
        email: { required: true, },
        cnpj: { required: true, },
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block'
    });
```

Comment: +1, This is exactly correct.  The `key:value` list of `field names: validation methods` must be contained within the `rules` option.  Otherwise, the plugin is left broken and inoperable.

Comment: Hey @Andrei Dvoynos and @Sparky! Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem still happens.

Comment: Hey @VictorAlencarSantos, it wasn't a suggestion.  Your posted code has rules outside of the `rules` option and that **will** break the plugin.  If you're still having trouble, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Hello @Sparky. Sorry, pal! I've already corrected it (with the above code) and tried again, but no success. Is there something else I can show here to help in the problem solving?